# How can I transfer installed programs from one laptop to another

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, transfer

I purchased a new laptop. The old laptop is Windows 10, the new one unfortunately is Windows 11.

I would like to transfer my installed programs from the old to the new, by making a backup of sorts on a USB stick. Files themselves aren't a problem as I can copy those. It is mainly the registry that's the issue.

My end result

1. Partition the new Hard Disk in exactly the same way as the old one (regarding the letters assigned), which I can do.
2. Transfer all the installed programs and their directories and files.

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot unfortunately

Comment: "*It is mainly the registry thats the issue.*" -- That's what "installation" takes care of for you. There may also be (hidden) configuration/data & library files besides the executable. You probably need to locate the original installation package(s).

Comment: You will need to install everything on the new computer.

Comment: @RohitGupta any thoughts on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The pragmatic option would be to disable security systems (TPM etc.), RAID, etc., clone the Hard Disk, and insert the clone into the new computer. Without going into details, if you are lucky Windows will start up. From there you can update drivers, Windows, etc.

For me that has worked as a quick fix surprisingly often. Note that this will bloat up your system, but it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Various apps store various data and settings in multiple places, mostly:

- registry, most often `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`
- config files with many different formats, e.g. `.json`, `.cfg`, `.ini`, `.xml`, etc.
- database files
  Some of these might not be transferable between systems as they might contain data specific to a machine.

You can try backing up individual apps with e.g. [CloneApp](https://www.mirinsoft.com/), though. It [supports a lot of apps](https://github.com/builtbybel/CloneApp/blob/master/docs/supported-apps.md), although it hasn't been developed recently and it's definitely not perfectly supporting the apps it lists. I am slowly working on a cross-system alternative, I'll update this once it comes out.

Comment: Thanks. Just the thing I am looking for (the github version of CloneApp) although it lacks many programs and hasn't been updated since 2020. Windows 10 in-place upgrade doesn't work for me (0xC1900101 - 0x30018), so I have to do a clean install and there is no other way to fix the current issue, but my computer has over 200 installed programs.. –